# Datatables buttons (export to excel) not displaying - Javascript /Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, datatables

Here I'm trying to add default excel export functionality for my JS project,

in `profiles.js` I have following code,

```
initDataTable({
    tableId: "#profilesStatusTable",
    orderVal: 1,
    sortingDirection: "asc",
    targetsVal: [0, 7],
    dom : 'Bfrtip',
        buttons : [ {
            extend: 'excel',
            text: 'Export To Excel'
        } ]
  });

      //Existing code for filter purpose
  $("#organizationFilterDropdown").dropdown();

  
  $("#organizationFilterDropdown").dropdown({
    onChange: function(value, text, $choice) {
      if (value === "Organisation") {
        // Reset option selected
        resetTableRecords(); // Call the function to reset the table records
      } else {
        var selectedOrganizationId = value;
        console.log(selectedOrganizationId);
  
        var profilesStatusTable = $("#profilesStatusTable").DataTable();
  
        profilesStatusTable.column(5).search(selectedOrganizationId).draw();
        
      }
    }
  });
```

But I cannot see any buttons , I also tried applying following in order where the table is implemented `_status_table.html.erb`,

```
<table>
  //code for table 
</table>



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  
href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  
href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />
  
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```